# Azure: Error Deploying VM from Generalised Image (Image Undeployable)

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine, vhd

I've been trying to use Powershell (following MS docs) to deploy a new VM from a generalised image but I keep getting this error.

```
New-AzureRmVM : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
ErrorCode: OSProvisioningClientError
ErrorMessage: OS provisioning for VM 'MyVM' failed. Error details: This installation of Windows is undeployable. Make sure the image has been properly prepared (generalized).
Instructions for Windows: https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-upload-image/ 
StartTime: 22/03/2017 10:06:24
EndTime: 22/03/2017 10:10:37
OperationID: 549f97d1-ca39-4bc5-bd6c-65e37a8d398f
Status: Failed
At C:\Visual Studio Projects\Deployment\VmSetup.ps1:97 char:1
+ New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmVM], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.NewAzureVMCommand
```

Trouble is that I did run a sysprep and generalised the image.

```
Code          : OSState/generalized
Level         : Info
DisplayStatus : VM generalized
Message       : 
Time          :
```

I'm also unable to start the VM again because it's told me it's generalised.

```
Failed to start virtual machine 'OtherVM'. Error: Operation 'start' is not allowed on VM 'OtherVM' since the VM is generalized.
```

Image saving script:

```
#Script to save image
$vmName = "OtherVM"
$rgName = "MyResourceGroup"
#Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName
Set-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName -Generalized
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName -Status
$vm.Statuses

#Save VM Image
Save-AzureRmVMImage -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vmName `
-DestinationContainerName "generalisedimages" -VHDNamePrefix "gen" `
#-Path "C:\VMTemplate\VmTemplate.json"
Write-Output "Imaged saved."
```

And the deploy script.

```
#
# VmDeploy.ps1
#
#Sign into Azure account
#Login-AzureRmAccount

# Name of the virtual machine. This example sets the VM name as "myVM".
$vmName = "MyVM"

#Set resource group and subnet name
$rgName = "MyResourceGroup"
$subnetName = "default"
$singleSubnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $subnetName -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/24

#Set location and vNet name
$location = "UK South"
$vnetName = "{0}-vnet" -f $rgName
$vnet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $vnetName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -AddressPrefix 10.0.0.0/16 -Subnet $singleSubnet

#Create public IP
$ipName = "{0}-ip" -f $vmName
$pip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $ipName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -AllocationMethod Dynamic

#Create NIC
$nicName = "{0}-nic" -f $vmName
$nic = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $nicName -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -SubnetId $vnet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $pip.Id

#Create network security group and allow RDP
$nsgName = "{0}-nsg" -f $vmName
$rdpRule = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name Rdp -Description "Allow RDP" `
    -Access Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 110 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix Internet -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 3389
$httpRule = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name Http -Description "Allow HTTP" `
    -Access Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 120 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix Internet -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 80
$httpsRule = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name Https -Description "Allow HTTPS" `
    -Access Allow -Protocol Tcp -Direction Inbound -Priority 130 `
    -SourceAddressPrefix Internet -SourcePortRange * `
    -DestinationAddressPrefix * -DestinationPortRange 443
$nsg = New-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -Name $nsgName -SecurityRules $rdpRule, $httpRule, $httpsRule

#Get completed virtual network
$vnet = Get-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $vnetName

#Uri of VM image
$imageURI = "https://*******.blob.core.windows.net/system/Microsoft.Compute/Images/generalisedimages/genosDisk.86g419f6-0de6-4331-hi54-32hse8de6bd4.vhd"
# Enter a new user name and password to use as the local administrator account 
# for remotely accessing the VM.
$cred = Get-Credential
# Name of the storage account where the VHD is located. This example sets the 
# storage account name as "myStorageAccount"
$storageRgName = $rgName
$storageAccName = "mystorage"

# Size of the virtual machine. This example creates "Standard_D2_v2" sized VM. 
# See the VM sizes documentation for more information: 
# https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/
$vmSize = "Standard_A1"

# Computer name for the VM. This examples sets the computer name as "myComputer".
$computerName = "New VM"

# Name of the disk that holds the OS. This example sets the 
# OS disk name as "myOsDisk"
$osDiskName = "OsDisk"

# Assign a SKU name. This example sets the SKU name as "Standard_LRS"
# Valid values for -SkuName are: Standard_LRS - locally redundant storage, Standard_ZRS - zone redundant
# storage, Standard_GRS - geo redundant storage, Standard_RAGRS - read access geo redundant storage,
# Premium_LRS - premium locally redundant storage. 
$skuName = "Standard_LRS"

# Get the storage account where the uploaded image is stored
$storageAcc = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $storageRgName -AccountName $storageAccName
Write-Output $storageAcc

# Set the VM name and size
$vmConfig = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $vmName -VMSize $vmSize

#Set the Windows operating system configuration and add the NIC
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vmConfig -Windows -ComputerName $computerName `
    -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm -Id $nic.Id

# Create the OS disk URI
$osDiskUri = '{0}vhds/{1}-{2}.vhd' `
    -f $storageAcc.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString(), $vmName.ToLower(), $osDiskName
Write-Output "OS Disk URI:" $osDiskUri

# Configure the OS disk to be created from the existing VHD image (-CreateOption fromImage).
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name $osDiskName -VhdUri $osDiskUri -CreateOption fromImage -SourceImageUri $imageURI -Windows
Write-Output $vm

# Create the new VM
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Location $location -VM $vm

$vmList = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $rgName
$vmList.Name
```

Comment: Why do say 'Trouble is that I did run a sysprep and generalised the image.'? There seems to be a problem in the generalized VHD. Have you generalized it on-premise? If yes, have you tried to provision a VM from this generalized VHD, on-premise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> OS provisioning for VM 'MyVM' failed. Error details: This installation
>   of Windows is undeployable. Make sure the image has been properly
>   prepared (generalized).

According to the error message, it seems you have **not** generalized VM correctly.
we should RDP to Azure VM, and run sysprep, in the System Preparation Tool dialog box, select **Enter System Out-of-Box Experience (OOBE)**, and make sure that the Generalize check box is selected. In Shutdown Options, select **Shutdown**.
[image]

More information about Generalize a Windows virtual machine, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-generalize-vhd?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json).

> I'm also unable to start the VM again because it's told me it's
>   generalised

Capture an image of an Azure widnows VM, this process **deletes** the original virtual machine after it is captured.
Prior to capturing an image of an Azure virtual machine, it is **recommended the target virtual machine be backed up**

Comment: please let me know if you would like further assistance.